# Is there a way to know the real CPU time elasped in a scala future?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, benchmarking

I want to know how many cpu time is spent in a future.
`ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime` is able to give this time but not for a future that is running in another thread.

I think the flowing code is able to give the end time but not the start time in the same thread.

```
future.map { result =>
  val end = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime
  (result, end - start)
}
```

ThreadMxBean is also capable to give the cpu time of a given thread but I think there is no whay to know the id of the thread before the future is run.

Comment: you can make `Future` block return `start` which should be calculated in first statement of `Future` block

Comment: how do you do this without modifying the code which generates the future?